# Polyglot persistence example

Tags: sql, nosql, persistence

I want to store my data on both SQL databases and NoSQL databases. This scenario can be described as Polyglot Persistence. Is there any code sample which implements Polyglot Persistence.

If you don't know Polyglot Persistence please read this [link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html)

Comment: very interesting. do you mind sharing wiht us why you need to store in both types of DBs?

Comment: Not a code sample, but see this slide deck, from slide 56: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html. It gives examples of how Twitter and Interactive Mediums (now SignalHQ, a CRM) are using it.

Answer (score 2):

Jimmy Bogard has a talk on exactly this topic - check it out on vimeo, http://vimeo.com/68320412 the source for his talk can be found here https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/tree/master/polyglotpersistence

Answer (score 1):

This technique is pretty common when handling large-scale data.  But, solutions are pretty specialized, so I can't really think of why there would be a generic code base for doing it.  The only exception might be putting memcached in front of other data stores.

A common example of doing what you are talking about is configuring an Apache Solr server to stay in sync with a SQL-based database.  Then you can do scored keyword/substring/synonym/stemmed/etc queries against Solr but do aggregations in SQL.

Another example is to use the same datastore, but store the same data in multiple aggregated formats.  For example, having a dataset that is rolled up by date (each day getting a record) can also be stored rolled up by user (each user getting a record).  Depending on the query you want to run, you choose the set that will give you the best performance.  If the data is large enough, the overhead of keeping the two sets synchronized more than pays for itself in increased query speed.